# Excel Pivot table updated missing columns

Tags: sql, excel, pivot

I have an Excel workbook which I use as template for a software written by me. 
In some worksheets I create some tables (one per worksheet), which contains some tags, which will be replaced by my software with some data picked up from a SQL query and stored in a new Excel workbook. In the template file I create a pivot table based on two tables. But when the new file is created and the pivot updated, only the rows are updated with the new data coming from the query, while the columns are litterally missing. Why?

[image: Table 1 in Template File] Table 1 in Template File [image: Table 2 in Template File] Table 2 in Template File [image: Table 1 with data from query] Table 1 with data from query [image: Table 2 with data from query] Table 2 with data from query [image: Pivot in Template File] Pivot in Template File [image: Pivot with data from query and missing columns] Pivot with data from query and missing columns

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you are missing the column selections (PivotTable Fields) on Pivot Table. Make sure you have selected the required columns in the template.

[image: Pivot ScreenShot]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I resolved making a new query to link the two tables and then making pivot upon one table only. The problem was effectively having more tables in the same pivot table